# jQuery Call within JavaScript class instances leads to last instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have problem with two classes and a jquery call. Unfortunatly if a call a method in one class it thinks it is the other one.

Here in detail:

I am writing a form, where the user can write down two customer numbers in two different input fields. The website will query each customernumber via jQuery AJAX and display details from the customer numbers.

So I wrote a class for not duplicating the code and assigning the behaviour to each input field.

```
CustomerData = function(settings){
    this.name = '';        
    this.street = '';
    this.zipcode ='';
    this.town = '';
    this.inputField = settings.inputfield;
    this.init();
}
CustomerData.prototype.init = function() {
    this.associateClassWithUi();
}

//here I assign the class with the inputfield via jQuery
CustomerData.prototype.associateClassWithUi = function() {
    _this = this;
    console.log("associate " +this.inputField);
    $(this.inputField).focus(function() {
        console.log(' focus on '+_this.inputField);
    });
    $(this.inputField).blur(function() {
        customerId = $(this).val();
        console.log("blur event " + _this.inputField);
        if(customerId != ''){
            _this.main(customerId);
        } else {
            _this.setEmpty();
            _this.propertiesToUi();   
        }
    });
}
```

I am defining the classes this way:

```
var DataCustomer1 = new CustomerData({
    inputField: '#customer1'
});

var DataCustomer2 = new CustomerData({
    inputField: '#customer2'
});
```

console.log gives me the following:

```
associate #customer1
associate #customer2
```

But clicking on the input fields (#customer1 and #customer2) I always get this

```
focus on #customer2
focus on #customer2
focus on #customer2
```

Of course if I change the order of instantiation

```
var DataCustomer2 = new CustomerData(...);
var DataCustomer1 = new CustomerData(...);
```

each of them thinks he is customer1

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Use var _this = this; otherwise it is being declared globally and overwritten each time.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable without var then it always becomes global. If you have this HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="customer1">Customer 1</li>
    <li id="customer2">Customer 2</li>
</ul>
```

The following code works as expected:

```
CustomerData = function(settings){
    this.inputField = settings.inputField;
    this.init();
}
CustomerData.prototype.init = function() {
    this.associateClassWithUi();
}

CustomerData.prototype.associateClassWithUi = function() {
    var _this = this;
    console.log("associate " +this.inputField);
    $(this.inputField).click(function() {
        console.log('click on '+_this.inputField);
    });
}

var DataCustomer1 = new CustomerData({
    inputField: '#customer1'
});

var DataCustomer2 = new CustomerData({
    inputField: '#customer2'
});
```

You can find more information about JavaScripts variables [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp)